# Unable to view all column when using AVG and WHERE in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, where-clause, window-functions

> book_isbn  user_iduser rating comment                                              date

```
1443434973,     2,       2,"Big Brother said this book was a four out of 5.",   2008-06-09
1501142976,     1,       3,"The book was scary, too scary.",                    2006-05-04
1594130000,     3,       4,"The moview was better.",                            2008-06-10
1501142976,     4,       5,"I have been inspired to pursue a career as a clown",2019-03-04
```

When I query

```
SELECT * ,AVG(rating)
FROM geektextdb.rating
WHERE book_isbn = '1501142976';`
```

I only get the second row in the table, but I am trying to get the 2nd and the 4th row.

P.S. I am not sure if this post is well formatted I use this site alot, but any tips on formatting would be helpful

Comment: Based on your query, it's correct that you will get 1 row.

Comment: Query actually shouldn't have run.  It just doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a window function, not aggregation:

```
SELECT r.*, AVG(rating) OVER (PARTITION BY book_isbn)
FROM geektextdb.rating r
WHERE book_isbn = '1501142976';
```

Comment: if you're trying to see all records, average for that book isbn repeated in each row, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid aggregation query. If you want the overall average of that particular `book_isbn`, then:

```
select avg(rating) avg_rating
from geektextdb.rating 
where book_isbn = '1501142976'
```

This gives you a scalar resultset (one row and one column), containing the average rating of that book.

On the other hand if you want all rows, along with the average rating repeated on each row, then you can use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
select r.*, avg(rating) over() avg_rating
from geektextdb.rating r
where book_isbn = '1501142976'
```

---

Here are the equivalent queries if you want the same result for all books at once, along with the average rating per book.

Aggregation (one row per book):

```
select book_isbn, avg(rating) avg_rating
from geektextdb.rating 
group by book_isbn
```

Windowing:

```
select r.*, avg(rating) over(partition by book_isbn) avg_rating
from geektextdb.rating r
```